# Show sheet with String Binding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Can I show a sheet using a String?
Please let me know if there's a way around it.

```
@State var selectedContactInfo: String?

.sheet(item: $selectedContactInfo){ item in MessageView(recipient: selectedContactInfo!) }
```

**I'm receiving this error:**

> Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that
> 'String' conform to 'Identifiable'

Comment: Wrap the string in a struct together with a uuid property and have it conform to Identifiable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String` could become `Identifiable`

Its `id` could be `self` because String is Hashable

```
extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String {self}
}
```